# Part of speech of 'next' in 'next door'

Tags: parts-of-speech, determiners

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Page 356) says this in a footnote:

> There is also a minor use of *such* that belongs with the determinatives: see §12. We might also include *last* and *next* as used in temporal deictic expressions such as *last week*, *next year*, etc., where they contrast with the central determinative *this*.

How about *next* in *I saw one of the guys from next door*? Doesn't *next* here also belong with the determinatives?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150363/discussion-on-question-by-jk2-part-of-speech-of-next-in-next-door); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

In CGEL's terminology, "next door" has to be a PP, not a NP or an AdvP, because it passes the *right* test: "They live right next door" is grammatical with *right* having the relevant spatial sense. In "Those are the guys from next door," we take the complement of "from" to be the PP "next door."

The question is whether "next door" is a single intransitive PP or a fossilized phrase consisting of a preposition *next* and a bare NP *door* (see pp. 617-620). It seems to me that, for the sake of treating this as a two-word expression and avoiding the "complex preposition" analysis (see p. 620), the latter analysis is preferable.

We should also note that this expression can take as a complement a PP headed by *to*, as in "We live next door to the factory." We can assign this either the right-branching analysis "next [door [to [the factory]]]" or the layered-head analysis "[[next [door]] [to [the factory]]]"; see pp. 620-623 for the relevant theoretical considerations.

**Edit:** It turns out that there's a difference between dialects on this point. According to [Cambridge Dictionary,](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/next-door) BrE allows sentences like %"Next door's having a party"; in those contexts, "next door" is indeed an NP, but that usage doesn't occur in AmE. But AmE does allow "next door" to be modified by *right,* making it clearly a PP by CGEL's criteria.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150362/discussion-on-answer-by-alphabet-part-of-speech-of-next-in-next-door); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: I've been thinking about the _right_ test. Yes, _They live right next door_ passes the test. But so does _Come right this way_, which doesn't make _this way_ a PP. In fact, in CGEL, _this way_ here is an NP. What do you think?

Comment: @JK2 Fair enough; the *right* test shows it can't be an AdvP, but it could still be an NP, as BillJ was claiming earlier. But I don't think you can square the NP analysis with the inadmissibility of "next door" as a subject in AmE. "Next month is going to be difficult" is fine, but %"Next door is having a party" is not. So there clearly isn't a parallel between "next door" and "next month."

Comment: Not all PPs allow _right_, though. Compare _I saw one of the guys from right next door_ with *_I saw one of the guys right from next door_. Go figure. // The question, then, is whether the inability of _next door_ being the subject in AmE proves that it's not an NP. I can't think of a noun phrase that cannot be subject, but I think this might be one of those cases.

Comment: @JK2 NPs are prototypically capable of functioning as subject, object, or predicative complement (p. 326); *next door* can't be any of those, I think, unlike *next month* or *that way.* (Of course, "Kim's house is next door to ours" is valid, but then it's a locative complement rather than a predicative one.)

Comment: But I think even _next month_ cannot be the object of a transitive verb, can it?

Comment: @JK2 "We might find next month difficult" sounds fine to me. Regardless, if "next door" can't occur in any of these positions I see no reason to posit that it's some special kind of NP.

Comment: But I can't find any data of "find(s)/found/finding next month + adjective" on COCA or Google Books.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151097/discussion-between-alphabet-and-jk2).

Comment: Here's a dialogue from the American movie "Scream 4": A: _Uhm, we re watching Shaun of the Dead._ B: _You know there's two zombies sitting outside your house in a car?_ A: _Yeah, they are cops. You wanna come up?_ B: _Angel of Death leave?_ A: _No, she's in the guest room._ B: _Forget it. Next door is close enough._  In the last sentence, _next door_ is used as the subject. And this is AmE.

Answer (score -2):

"*Next door*" is parsed as a single lexical unit, and is either an adverb, an adjective (spelled "*next-door*" ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/next-door_3))), or a noun  (as in the sentence of the OP ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/next-door_1?q=next+door))).

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/next-door_1?q=next+door)) **next door** noun
> [uncountable + singular or plural verb] (British English, informal)
>
> - ​the people who live in the house or flat next to yours
> - Is that next door's dog?
> - The Volvo belongs to next door.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150360/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-part-of-speech-of-next-in-next-door); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.